# VIM: Finding and replacing first N occurrences of a word

Tags: vim, vi

I am editing a file and i want to change only a specific word with another word, but only for first N occurrences. I tried multiple commands

`N :s/word/newword/`

`:%s/word/newword/count`

And other commands that i could find on google. But none of them works.

EDIT:: Vim commands is preferred. But Vim script can also be used. I don't have any prior experience in vim scripting.

Comment: `:s/word/newword/N` is the only valid command, but that would replace the first occurrence on the next N lines.
And if you used the /g flag, it'll replace all occurrences on the next N lines. Neither do the the exact count you desire.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using a disposable recording allows you to control exactly how many changes you do:

```
qq             " start recording in register q
/foo<CR>       " search for next foo
cgnbar<Esc>    " change it to bar
q              " end recording
11@q           " play recording 11 times
```

See `:help recording` and `:help gn`.

Another way, using `:normal`:

```
:norm! /foo<C-v><CR>cgnbar<C-v><Esc>     <-- should look like this: :norm! /foo^Mcgnbar^[
11@:
```

See `:help :normal` and `:help @:`.

Or simply:

```
:/foo/|s//bar<CR>
11@:
```

Comment: @romainl Can you explain meaning of each line and attribute?

Comment: @Ignited, I've added `:help` pointers. Ask me if you have questions on specific parts of my answer.

Comment: Wow what a clever use of `cgn` . Any specific resource where I can get started with such commands and vim scripting too?

Comment: +1. `gn` also goes great with the `.`. Can skip patterns with `n`.

Answer (score 12):

Although a bit longer, you can do:

```
:call feedkeys("yyyq") | %s/word/newword/gc
```

to replace the first 3 occurrences and then stop.
You can change the amount of `y`'s for more or less replacements. (Can also use `n` to skip some)

Explanation: this is feeding `y` keystrokes into the `/c` confirm option of the substitution command.

Comment: `:call feedkeys(repeat("y", 3) . "q") | %s/test/toast/gc` for a specific amount. Where 3 is the number of occurrences to replace.

Comment: I laughed a little when I realized I still had my test/toast in there from testing, but you get the point :)

Comment: This solution is easy both to remember and to read! Very elegant! I like it way more than a "complex succession of cryptic vim magic characters"... ;) Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure about specifying the first N occurrences, but I often use this command:

```
:%s/word/newword/gc
```

Vim then asks for confirmation of each occurrence of `word` so you can selectively change some but not others.

Comment: Will be quite tedious and high chances of human counting error when N is large

Comment: Yes, that's true. But when N is not large, it gives a lot more control over what is changed.

Comment: Also, this is an easier to understand command than the others proposed in this thread.

Answer (score 2):

My [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602) provides (among many others) a command that takes answers in the form of either `yyynyn` or `1-5`:

```
:%SubstituteSelected/word/newword/g 1-5
```